# Как проверить существует ли открытый порт на Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, proxy

У меня сделан сервер на Node.js и определён прокси сервер.

```
http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});


this.httpServer = https.createServer(credentials, function(request, response) {
....

  proxy.web(request, response, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5001' });
}
```

Если у меня проксируемый порт существует всё хорошо работает.
Но если у меня этот порт отсутствует у меня появляется ошибка.
Я её могу в callback -е но после этого, когда появляется порт проксирование не происходит.

Наверное я могу новый инстанс прокси сервера сделать и он заработает, но как мне проверить существует ли открытый порт, что бы если он не существует не создавать прокси и не ставить проверку ошибок в этом месте ?

Comment: По сути ваша задача сводится к проверке открыт ли порт. Это можно сделать обычной linux-тулзой, например `nc -zvw10 127.0.0.1 5001`. Я это скопировал из поиска по `linux how to check port open`. Теперь это нужно как-то сделать на nodejs. Если не знаете - есть spawn. Или средствами самого nodejs можно сделать, там есть работа с tcp. А ну вот, [нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860354/in-nodejs-how-do-i-check-if-a-port-is-listening-or-in-use#29872303)

Comment: spawn не хотелось бы использовать если есть стандартные средства. В ссылке, которую вы скинули предлагают каждый раз для проверки создавать http сервер. Не думаю что это грамматный вариант.

Comment: Да, сервер создавать излишне, нужно создать клиент. Хотя... разница небольшая. Написал пример ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В NodeJS есть [модуль работы с сетью](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html). В коде ниже осуществляется соединение с сокетом, по результатам которого выводится сообщение yes/no.

```
const net = require("net");

class PortChecker {

    async testPort(port, host) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const socket = new net.Socket();

            socket.on("connect", () => {
                socket.destroy();
                resolve("yes");
            });

            socket.on("timeout", () => {
                socket.destroy();
                resolve("no");
            });

            socket.on("error", () => {
                socket.destroy();
                resolve("no");
            });

            socket.connect(port, host);

        });
    }

}

let pc = new PortChecker;

pc.testPort(22, "127.0.0.1").then((result) => {
    console.log(`Is port open? ${result}`);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Fatal error:", err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал про этот метод ) Завтра проверю, но я думаю будет работать.